# How to get the ["Manufacturer", "FileSize", "FileType"] of a file in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, wmic

I need to get the WMIC information of a file, like the CopyRight value, and the Mime type of the application. I searched a lot and could not find the solution anywhere. I could not find any .net libraries for the same.

Comment: I am not sure why the question is downvoted, but please provide a reason for the downvote.

Comment: Have you tried [reading the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393964(v=vs.85).aspx)?